# Improve execution time of very slow python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dictionary

This is my first post so please bear with me. I need some help to optimize the below one liner.

```
pd_df.loc[flag, 'COL_{}'.format(col_number)] = pd_df.loc[flag,'COL{}'.format(col_number)].apply(lambda x: x + str(userid) + "@")
```

pd_df : Panda data frame contains 2M rows

flag= numpy one dimension boolean array to filter/update many rows at once in pd_df

COL_{}'.format(col_number)= Random column number as per main FOR loop like COL_1,COL_5 upto COL_15 (Data type string with 5000 character length)

In general what this code does it, first filter the rows to be updated according to the flag and column to be updated as per column number and append list of user id in those multiple rows and single column with @ as delimiter. For examples @userid1@userid2@userid2 and so one .

This line of code consume 75% of my overall time due to slow pandas data frame loc function and large no of rows i.e 2M.

Can someone please help me to convert this piece into something more optimized way like dictionary/numpy data type.

Below is Output above code is creating. On the basis of Country and Category user id related, its userid is appended to that column number. Suppose Col_1 can contains upto userid3 and column2 upto userid7 and so on until col15.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Liva

Comment: If you show more of you code there might be other optimizations that help more.

Comment: Other part is already optimized and just a loop that goes through list of userids to check in which row and columns it will append with delimiter

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there sample input so we can copy it?

Comment: Sample input ? I don't understand it. Do you want sample input data in some excel format ? The code I shared is small part of large one and input to this code is all in memory not from local file. After loading the initial file we do lot a calculation based on logic. So input data might not be useful. I just want to know some better way to replace this one liner code which is taking all my execution time.

Comment: Sorry if I am not clear enough in first instance.

Comment: Added an output image. For example in the loop of user2, flag will be set to TRUE for all rows except row6 and then its id will be appended in col1 in all rows except row6. flag is one dimensional numpy array of same length as pandas dataframe pd_df.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed that `apply()` can be slow. You want to try to take advantage of vectorized operations whenever possible. Try using the concatenation operator (`+`). Does this work any faster

```
pd_df.loc[flag, 'COL_{}'.format(col_number)] = pd_df.loc[flag,'COL{}'.format(col_number)] + (str(userid) + "@")
```

Furthermore, not sure if it would help, but some of these strings should be precalculated (probably Python is caching them already but in case not):

```
col_name = 'COL_{}'.format(col_number)
suffix = str(userid) + "@"
pd_df.loc[flag, col_name] = pd_df.loc[flag, col_name] + suffix
```

Comment: Thanks. By removing the apply operator and using f strings, time has been reduced from 75% to 15%. for this line. I am expecting some more improvement if there is some data type that i can use such as numpy array or dictionary instead of panda frame.

Comment: Glad you have succeeded in these improvements so far. If switching to f strings made a difference, then that means the string concatenation was being calculated multiple times. Try the pre-calculation I have above, maybe it will help some more.

Comment: I did that earlier along with other changes.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points:

1. [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) are always faster than `str.format`, use them whenever possible:

   ```
   In [3]: fmt = "{foo}"
   In [4]: %timeit fmt.format(foo=5)
   299 ns ± 21.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
   In [5]: foo = 5
   In [6]: %timeit f"{foo}"
   79.2 ns ± 2.31 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
   ```
2. It seems `userid` is independent of the dataframe, I'm not sure why you are using `apply`, just use [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

   ```
   In [8]: userid = "abcdef"
   In [9]: pd.Series('abc def ghi jkl'.split()) + f'@{userid}'
   Out[9]:
   0    abc@abcdef
   1    def@abcdef
   2    ghi@abcdef
   3    jkl@abcdef
   dtype: object
   ```

So the final approach could be something like this:

```
for num in range(5):
    flag = ... # calculate flag
    df[flag, f"col_{num}"] = df[flag, f"col_{num}"] + f"@{userid}"
```

Comment: Thanks .It helps to reduce the time for this line of code from 75% to 15%. I am expecting some more improvement if there is some other data type that i can use such as numpy array or dictionary instead of panda frame.

Comment: There's not much difference between pandas dataframe and numpy arrays.  pandas dataframes are numpy arrays underneath.  Dictionaries are slow, but I'm not sure why that's relevant here, as you are working with array/tabular data.  It's difficult to suggest anything more if you do not share your code, specially when it comes to performance.

Answer (score 0):

`apply` is one of the slower ways to run a function per item.

```py
pd_df.loc[flag, f’COL_{col_number}’] = pd_df.loc[flag, f’COL_{col_number}’].map(lambda x: f’{x}{userid}@‘)
```

Comment: Thanks. Replaced the apply with map and now its more slow. I guess if we can convert this panda data frame to new object(dp/dict) then there can be some improvement. Root cause is this loc function and joining values with delimiter(@) on large dataset and with multiple rows at once.